# How to unit test ViewModel consuming methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, viewmodel

I want to test a helper method that takes a ViewModel as an argument. The problem I'm having is that the test seems to require I instantiate and assign all of the Models that my ViewModel uses. In the example I give below, it's not such a big deal because there are only a few but in the actual VM I'm working on there are a ton. Is there some other way to do this so I don't have to create and assign every object?

Example code for illustration purposes...

**The Models**

```
public class Meal
{
    public int MealID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

public class Beverage
{
    public int BeverageID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

public class Desert
{
    public int DesertID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}
```

**The ViewModel**

```
public class DinnerViewModel
{
    public Meal Meal { get; set; }
    public Beverage Beverage { get; set; }
    public Desert Desert { get; set; }

    public decimal SalesTax { get; set; }
    public bool SeniorDiscount { get; set; }
}
```

**The Helper**

```
public class Calculator
{
    public decimal Total(DinnerViewModel dvm)
    {
        decimal subtotal = dvm.Meal.Cost + dvm.Beverage.Cost + dvm.Desert.Cost;

        if (dvm.SeniorDiscount)
        {
            subtotal = subtotal - (subtotal * 0.1M);
        }

        return subtotal + (subtotal * dvm.SalesTax);
    }
}
```

**The Test**

```
[TestMethod]
public void CalculatorReturnsCorrectTotalForNonSenior()
{
    DinnerViewModel dvm = new DinnerViewModel();
    dvm.Meal.Cost = 7M;
    dvm.Beverage.Cost = 1M;
    dvm.Desert.Cost = 2M;
    dvm.SalesTax = 0.08M;
    dvm.SeniorDiscount = false;

    Calculator calc = new Calculator();

    decimal expected = 10.80M;
    decimal actual = calc.Total(dvm);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "The actual value does not match the expected value.");
}
```

This results in a "NullReferenceException" error. As I said, I can create and assign the necessary objects...

```
[...]
Meal meal = new Meal();
dvm.Meal = meal;
dvm.Meal.Cost = 7M;
[...]
```

...and, once they're all done, the test succeeds—but that seems like a ton of work on a larger VM and I get a feeling that there's gotta be something I can do to make this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see NullReferenceException, because Meal, Beverage and Desert instances are not assigned to corresponding properties of DinnerViewModel when you are instantiating it. So, all these properties are `null`. You should create and assign new objects before accessing these properties. You can use constructor of view model:

```
public class DinnerViewModel
{
    public DinnerViewModel()
    {
        Meal = new Meal();
        Beverage = new Beverage();
        Desert = new Desert();
    }

    public Meal Meal { get; set; }
    public Beverage Beverage { get; set; }
    public Desert Desert { get; set; }

    public decimal SalesTax { get; set; }
    public bool SeniorDiscount { get; set; }
}
```

Also I like to create some helper methods which return stubs for tests. It removes duplication and makes your tests clear:

```
private DinnerViewModel CreateTenDollarsDinner()
{
    return new DinnerViewModel {
        Meal = new Meal { Cost = 7M },
        Beverage = new Beverage { Cost = 1M },
        Desert = new Desert { Cost = 2M },
        SalesTax = 0.08M,
        SeniorDiscount = false
    };
}

[TestMethod]
public void CalculatorReturnsCorrectTotalForNonSenior()
{
    DinnerViewModel dvm = CreateTenDollarsDinner();    
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    Assert.AreEqual(10.80M, calc.Total(dvm));
}
```

Comment: I identified another thing I was doing wrong that isn't apparent in my example code. When a Model has a FK like `public int AnotherModelID { get; set; }` and a Navigation Property like `public virtual AnotherModel AnotherModel { get; set; }`, it is possible in the View, for example, to access a property like `vm.Model.AnotherModel.Property` but it seems that this doesn't work when testing. In addition to instantiating the Models in the constructor, I had to add the Models to the VM like `AnotherModel AnotherModel = new AnotherModel();`

Answer (score 0):

Either your models (Meal, Beaverage and Dessert) are ViewModels too, or your DinnerViewModel is not really a ViewModel.

A ViewModel has the purpose to provide directly usable values for the View.

Based on your unit test example it would be more appropriate to put your Calculator.Total helper method directly to the DinnerViewModel and expose the total calculated value as a property to the view:

```
public class DinerViewModel
{
    public Meal Meal { get; set; }
    public Beverage Beverage { get; set; }
    public Desert Desert { get; set; }

    public decimal SalesTax { get; set; }
    public bool SeniorDiscount { get; set; }

    public decimal TotalCostOfDinner
    {
        get
        {
            decimal subtotal = 0M;
            if(Meal != null) subtotal += Meal.Cost;
            if(Beverage != null) subtotal += Beverage.Cost;
            if(Desert != null) subtotal += Desert.Cost;

            if (SeniorDiscount) subtotal -= subtotal * 0.1M;

            return subtotal + (subtotal * SalesTax);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your View can take the correct TotalCostOfDinner directly from the DinnerViewModel.

Now for the unit testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TotalCostOfDinnerReturnsCorrectTotalForNonSenior()
{
    DinnerViewModel dvm = new DinnerViewModel
    {
        Meal = new Meal { Cost = 7M },
        Beverage = new Beverage { Cost = 1M },
        Desert = new Desert { Cost = 2M },
        SalesTax = 0.08M,
        SeniorDiscount = false
    };


    decimal expected = 10.80M;
    decimal actual = dvm.TotalCostOfDinner;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "The actual value does not match the expected value.");
}
```

Comment: My actual ViewModel is being used to create an inventory data-entry form (adding new items to a database). To do this all in one page, I have to use a VM to pull together many different Models. After the form is submitted, I have to map the data in the VM to their corresponding Models in order to save everything to the database. Instead of doing this mapping in the Controller, I moved the logic into a Helper. The Controller sends the VM to the Helper, the Helper does its thing, saves the new Item to the database, and returns `true` if all went well.